# Wagtail 2.12 translations problem with wagtail_localize and StreamField

Tags: localization, wagtail, wagtail-localize

I am using wagtail built-in translations system with wagtail_localize.
For StreamFields with nested content, only external content is available for translation.

Look at this example:

```
class Carousel(blocks.StructBlock):
  title = blocks.CharBlock(label='Titolo')
  text = blocks.RichTextBlock(label='Testo')
  items = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.StructBlock([
            ('tab_label', blocks.CharBlock(label='Testo visualizzato sulla tab')),
            ('title', blocks.CharBlock(label='Titolo')),
            ('text', blocks.RichTextBlock(label='Testo')),
            ('photo', ImageChooserBlock(label='Foto')),
            ('page', QuickPageLinkBlock(required=False)),
            ('color', NativeColorBlock(default="#085083", label = 'Colore per il titolo')),
        ]), label = 'Lista slide')
  
  class Meta:
    icon='snippet'
    label = 'Carosello'
    template = 'blocks/carousel.html'
```

Only title and text are available for translations, but not all the items.
[image]
I also need to translate items. How can i solve?

Moreover it seems that linked pages contained in snippets (in pages it works) cannot be translated, but I need to change the link to the correct language page.

Can someone help me?
Thanks,
Sabrina

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **using a StreamBlock instead of ListBlock** for items.
The content of StreamBlock is translatable. I don't think ListBlocks can be translated yet ([see here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-localize/issues/22))

```
# Do not do this:
items = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.StructBlock(...))

# Do this instead:
items = blocks.StreamBlock([('item', blocks.StructBlock(...))])
```